# How to disable and enable anchor tag based on condition using php

Tags: php, if-statement, anchor

How do i disable and enable an anchor tag based on order_status condition? I want to make my receipt button only be able to click when the order_status been updated to ($irow['order_status'] == 5. It would be much appreciated if you all can provide me a code demo to show me how should I implement this using php. Thanks!

I tried the below codes but it wasn't working. It shows the error of `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'order_id' (T_STRING)`. I do not know why does this happens. Can you guys give me a help to implement this?

```
<?php
      if($order_status == 5){
          print ' <a id="receiptbtn" target="_blank" 
        href="
        receipt.php?order_id=<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>" 
        class="btn addtocart" style="font-size: 12px;"><span class="iconify" data-icon="bx:bx-download" data-inline="false"></span> Receipt</a>';
          }
          else{
          print '<a href="" class="disabled-link">Receipt</a>';
          }
      ?>
```

Comment: You don't put `<?php` inside strings. Use string concatenation.

Comment: @Barmar if i don't put php, then how do I link it to the respective page?

Comment: You use string concatenation. `print 'string1' . $variable . 'string2';`

Answer (score 2):

You're already in `<?php` execution mode, you can't use `<?php echo` to include a string. `<?php` is being treated as literal text in the string, and the `'` in `$row['order_id']` is ending the string that you're printing.

Use the string concatenation operator to combine a variable with the string literal.

To disable a link use `href="#"`. `href=""` means to reload the page.

```
<?php
    if($irow['order_status'] == 5){
        print ' <a id="receiptbtn" target="_blank" 
            href="receipt.php?order_id=' . $row['order_id'] . '" 
            class="btn addtocart" style="font-size: 12px;"><span class="iconify" data-icon="bx:bx-download" data-inline="false"></span> Receipt</a>';
    }
    else{
        print '<a href="#" class="disabled-link">Receipt</a>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: but my button can't link to the page that I want. It just reloads within  the page

Comment: That's what `href=""` means. Use `href="#"` to make the link do nothing.

Comment: but the buttons work when the `order_status` is not `==5`. Can I know how can I disable it when the order status is not 5?

Comment: `$order_status` should be `$irow['order_status']`

Comment: but i got the error of `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`

Comment: The code needs to be inside the `while ($irow = $iquery->fetch_assoc())` loop.

Comment: so i just add the code into the while loop to make it work?

Comment: I think so. You posted lots of code that I didn't read carefully, so I'm not sure exactly where it belongs. But since it depends on that field, it has to be in the loop.